# How to properly send a lot of email alerts with PHP?

Tags: php, email

We have an internal message board. If a user posts a note then all other users that have access to the thread are sent an email alert. So if there are 20 users on a thread then you could see bursts of 100s of emails over only a couple minutes.

Currently the email alerts are sent with the PHP `mail()` function. One time we got some local relay alerts and I think our server IP was blacklisted for a short period of time. And I think these negative consequences happened because of an email alert burst that uses `mail()`.

Is the solution simply to use anything other than `mail()`, or is there more to it? How can I reproduce/test the local relays and blacklisting so that I am sure the issue is solved?

Answer (score -1):

If you're sending large amounts of email the best thing you can do is use a third party email provider. There are several that offer API/SMTP services and will not be blacklisted because they work on a reputation system. Most offer composer packages you can drop in and configure relatively quickly.

- [SendGrid](https://sendgrid.com) / [sendgrid-api](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-php) - We use this to send around 2 million emails a month without issue.
- [Mailgun](https://www.mailgun.com) / [mailgun-php](https://github.com/mailgun/mailgun-php)
- [Mandrill](http://mandrill.com) / [mandrill-api-php](https://bitbucket.org/mailchimp/mandrill-api-php)

Each have their pros and cons and some offer free emails to a certain limit.

If this isn't an option you should create a dedicated email server that has all the correct DKIM/SPF records that over time will become reputable over time however it'll still slow down when you're sending many emails as it'll be limited to 1 email at a time and if it encounters a slow connection it can take a while to complete. If email is important a third party provider is definitely the best way to go.